# Android compose Topbar

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Hi im noob android developer
[image: phone]

how to change this color black..

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TestTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    // Dynamic color is available on Android 12+
    dynamicColor: Boolean = true,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colorScheme = when {
        dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
        }

        darkTheme -> DarkColorScheme
        else -> LightColorScheme
    }
    val view = LocalView.current
    if (!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            val window = (view.context as Activity).window
            window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.primary.toArgb()
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = darkTheme
        }
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )
}
```

Its my theme file

i cant find anyway..

want to change black or my screen color

Comment: Can you share the code where you define your top app bar?

Comment: @tomerpacific
TopAppBar(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(48.dp),
        title = {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxHeight(),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
            ) {            }
        },
        actions = {        },
        colors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors(
            containerColor = Color.White,
        )
    )

Comment: Please edit your question with the code so it will be easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of your TopAppBar, you need to change the color attributes ([documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/components/app-bars)).

I.E.

```
Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        TopAppBar(
            colors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors(
                containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer,   /// <-----
                titleContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary, /// <----
            ),
            ...
        )
    },
) { innerPadding ->
    ...
   }
}
```

In your code, you are setting it to be always white:

```
TopAppBar( 
         modifier = Modifier .height(48.dp), 
         title = { 
                   Box( 
                       modifier = Modifier .fillMaxHeight(),
                       contentAlignment = Alignment.Center, ) {
                              } }, 
         actions = { }, 
         colors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors( containerColor = Color.White, /// <----- )
 )
```